# Check function template validity in C++14 when using -Waddress

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

When compiling this code with `-Waddress`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string.h>

template <typename T, void (*func)(T*) = nullptr>
struct Caller {
    Caller(T* ptr = nullptr)
    {
        std::cout
            << "Creating caller " << ptr
            << ", is function " << std::is_function<decltype(func)>()
            << ", is null " << std::is_null_pointer<decltype(func)>()
            << ", function is " << func
            << std::endl;

        if (func)
        {
            std::cout << "Running for " << ptr << " func " << func << std::endl;
            func(ptr);
        }
    }
};

void free_char(char *c) { free(c); }

int main() {
    Caller<char, free_char>(strdup("Test"));
    Caller<const char>("Test2");
    return 0;
}
```

it will fail with:

```
/tmp/foo.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Caller<T, func>::Caller(T*) [with T = char; void (* func)(T*) = free_char]’:
/tmp/foo.cpp:36:40:   required from here
/tmp/foo.cpp:13:33: warning: the address of ‘void free_char(char*)’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
```

A workaround is using something like `if (auto f = func) f(ptr);` but i'd like to have something that is statically checked at compile time.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166386/g-waddress-may-misunderstand-my-meaning) mentions the usage of template specialization, but a part that here we're handling a struct, this is a case where i'd like to use static template checks.

Comment: Sorry, why can't you use template specialization?

Comment: Why not just take a function pointer in the constructor? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60f81dec07918597

Comment: `if constexpr` in C++17.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, I was aware of it, but as said we're not ready yet for that :)

Comment: @NathanOliver cause it needs to be a type, where I just generate new ones by passing a new template.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply providing a no-op function by default instead of a null pointer? This gets rid of the `if` altogether and makes the code cleaner in general.

```
template<typename T>
void no_op(T*) {}

template <typename T, void (*func)(T*) = no_op<T>>
struct Caller {
    static_assert(func != nullptr, "don't pass nullptr");
    Caller(T* ptr = nullptr)
    {
        std::cout
            << "Creating caller " << ptr
            << ", is function " << std::is_function<decltype(func)>()
            << ", is null " << std::is_null_pointer<decltype(func)>()
            << ", function is " << func
            << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Running for " << ptr << " func " << func << std::endl;
        func(ptr);
    }
};
```

Comment: Fact is that in my case I don't just want not to call function if not valid, but also change behavior.... And in such case, I guess checking for no_op function would still generate the same (is always true) thing...